# Constraint Violation Exception ORA-00001

Tags: oracle, hibernate, indexing, ora-00001

I am using Oracle database. We are seeing frequent failures in calls to our service. When I looked at the logs I am seeing following exceptions on a table

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBSCHEMA.IDX_CO_DETAILS) violated.

I have checked the Index on the table for index name DBSCHEMA.IDX_CO_DETAILS .

It did not include any column's( INCLUDE_COLUMN is null) . How can I know what is this constraint for ? Is it primary key constraint?

We are using hibernate for ORM. Below is the back trace in hibernate context

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [unique constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1642) enforces, well, uniqueness. It will allow nulls, unlike a [primary key constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1646).

Your error means that you are inserting duplicate data when the database has been configured to explicitly prohibit that.

You can find out what constraints are on a table by running the following query on [all_constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1046.htm#i1576022). The link decodes the column `CONSTRAINT_TYPE`, for instance `P` is a primary key and `U` a unique key.

```
select *
  from all_constraints uc
 where uc.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
   and owner = 'DBSCHEMA'
```

To find out what columns are in a constraint use [`all_cons_columns`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1044.htm#sthref1057) instead, or combining the two into one query:

```
select uc.*, ucc.column_name, ucc.position
  from all_constraints uc
  join all_cons_columns ucc
    on uc.owner = ucc.owner
   and uc.table_name = ucc.table_name
   and uc.constraint_name = ucc.constraint_name
 where uc.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
   and uc.owner = 'DBSCHEMA'
```

To either query you can add the additional condition `and constraint_name = 'IDX_CO_DETAILS'` to find out details of the specific constraint that seems to be causing your problem.

---

Your comment is a little surprising for a couple of reasons. Even a system created constraint, for instance one that was defined in-line when the table was created without a name being specified should show up. Also, the constraint name `IDX...` implies that it's an index.

IF you run the following query it should tell you if the object exists in the database:

```
select *
  from all_objects
 where object_name = 'IDX_CO_DETAILS'
```

I would expect that the `OBJECT_TYPE` returned by this query is `'INDEX'`.

Following on from that the following query will return every index with that name, the type of index, the table it is associated with and the owner of that table.

```
select *
  from all_indexes
 where index_name = 'IDX_CO_DETAILS'
```

Judging by your error I would further expect that the column `UNIQUNESS` returned by this query is `'UNIQUE'`.

This should help you track down the object.

You can also use the system package [`dbms_metadata`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS640) to track down the DDL of the object; be careful it returns a clob.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX','IDX_CO_DETAILS', schema => 'DBSCHEMA') 
  from dual
```

the parameter `schema` is optional.

Comment: I have run both the queries. I have removed the owner as it was returning no rows. None of the constraints have the name IDX_CO_DETAILS and there are no Unique key constraints. Can it be the index constraint created by oracle for primary key ?

Comment: Yes it is present in the all_indexes table. But when I run the last query for dbms_metadata, I got object not found error.
We have another internal tool to fetch the table meta data. Found that IDX_CO_DETAILS is based three columns. So it should be failing while creating the index. So does it make sense to add a constraint on index rather than on the table itself?. And in this case we are getting  JDBC batch update exception. Can this would have been avoided if we had constraint on table rather than on Index?

Comment: If the index is unique by definition it has a unique constraint associated with it; i.e. it is constrained on the table by default. The fact that you can't find it in `all_constraints` or using `dbms_metadata` is fairly suspicious; is the table in the same schema you're querying these from? The _reason_ for a unique constraint/index is to avoid duplicates and speed up queries. _If_ there is a valid reason for the constraint then the code that is updating the table is incorrect rather than the constraint itself.

Comment: I can find it in all_constraints, I am using the correct schema.  Regarding your last point                               >>If there is a valid reason for the constraint then the code that is updating the table is incorrect rather than the constraint itself.                                                               How can it be the issue with code, database is supposed to through exception in this case, how can the code care take care of it?  Are you referring hibernate mapping files?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to insinuate that the code was _literally_ wrong; more that if the constraint is for a reason maybe you should reconsider why you're doing the update / insert that you are.