# PK violated When I insert values into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, insert, unique

I'm new to SQL Oracle. I'm trying to "merge" two tables.

```
PAYMENT_COMMON ---> TABLE A
   (PCO_NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL, 
    ID_BUILD NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL, 
    NUM_DEPARMENT NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
    PGC_DATE_CANCELATION DATE NOT NULL, 
    PGC_AMMOUNT_PAY NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    ID_VIA_PAYMENT NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL);
```

and a table called payment_common1 (Same rows and columns as payment_common)  which had 111 values that don't are in `PAYMENT_COMMON`.

So I tried to add those values without duplicate it using the query:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_COMMON(PCO_NUMBER, 
    ID_BUILD NUMBER, 
    NUM_DEPARTMENT,
    PGC_DATE_CANCELATION, 
    PGC_AMMOUNT_PAY,
    ID_VIA_PAYMENT) 
    SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_COMMON
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_COMMON1;
```

but it returns

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.PK_PAYMENT_COMMON) violated
```

Hope someone could help me to find out my error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constraint Violation Exception ORA-00001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969693/constraint-violation-exception-ora-00001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check which column(s) make up the primary key index (PK_PAYMENT_COMMON). Do this by the following statement:

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'PAYMENT_COMMON'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

But the main problem with your `INSERT` statement is that rows already exist in the `PAYMENT_COMMON` table, so don't need to insert them again.
Also, it is better to be explicit than implicit when performing DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`). Therefore, avoid `SELECT *` and specify all of the columns. This helps to avoid unexpected errors if the table structure changes.

Assuming that `PCO_NUMBER` is the primary key (change the `WHERE` clause within the `EXISTS` statement, depending on the results of the above), the query should be the following:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_COMMON
(
    PCO_NUMBER, 
    ID_BUILD, 
    NUM_DEPARTMENT,
    PGC_DATE_CANCELATION, 
    PGC_AMMOUNT_PAY,
    ID_VIA_PAYMENT
) 
SELECT 
PCO_NUMBER, 
ID_BUILD, 
NUM_DEPARTMENT,
PGC_DATE_CANCELATION, 
PGC_AMMOUNT_PAY,
ID_VIA_PAYMENT
FROM PAYMENT_COMMON1 C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM PAYMENT_COMMON C
                    WHERE C.PCO_NUMBER = C1.PCO_NUMBER 
                 );
```